# Localizing GraphQL results when using Relay

Tags: javascript, graphql, relay, graphql-js

I'm hoping someone in the `GraphQL/Relay` community has encountered this issue.

We have a multilingual system, which means that the results are localized. So we have an argument called `lang` which is passed down to the field resolvers.

Queries are written as such:

```
query {
  viewer(lang: ja) {
    books { <- Type is `Book`
      id
      title <- This would be localized to Japanese.
    }
  }
}
```

Which would return:

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "books": [
        {
          "id": "SOMETHINGSOMETHING123",
          "name": "ハリー・ポッター" // "Harry Potter" in Japanese.
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is possible due to the resolver for translatable fields looking like this (note that I am using [dataloader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader)):

```
...
resolve: (parent, args, ast, { rootValue }) => {
  const { language } = rootValue
  const { BookLoader } = rootValue.loaders
  return BookLoader.TranslationsLoader(language).load(parent.id).then(translations => translations[parent.id].title || parent.title)
}
```

If a translation exists, it will use that instead of the original value.
This was working fine until we introduced `Relay` into our project.

We want to utilize Relay's `node`, and have made it partially work, i.e.:

```
query {
  node(id: "SOMETHINGSOMETHING123") {
    ...b
  }
}
fragment b on Book {
  id
  name
}
```

But since using `node` can't take arguments like `viewer` can,
there is no way to pass the language.

How would I pass `language parameters` to the resolver which would work with both standard queries and nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Since **graphql-js v0.6**, each resolver receives a `context` object as the third parameter. This is good for passing contextual info from the server to GraphQL's execution phase. We use it, for example, to handle authentication and authorization. You could pass in the desired language there. If you use **express-graphql** or **koa-graphql**, they pass the `request` object as the `context` by default. You could examine the headers from the resolver.

EDIT: Here is an example of handling a session in a graphql resolver using express-graphql: [express-graphql](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#user-content-combining-with-other-express-middleware)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. We are using the context, it just won't work when we query via Node ID for Relay.

Comment: Thanks for the edit too. I'll edit my answer to reflect this, but these queries are thrown kind of on behalf of the user, meaning that I may want the results in Japanese, but you may want them in English.